# When I call my API on postman and pass the data it display response 429 too many requests

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-429

I created blog API when I call and run the API with passing data Is says 429 too many requests

I am trying to run the API but it say 429 too many requests so give the possible solution on that.
i am unable to getting it so.

Comment: have you added rate limitting in your api during development?

Comment: Try sending fewer requests in a short period of time. Check what the rate limit is set to. We can't help you further without any more info about the setup. See also [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the throttle parameter in app/Http/Kernel.php.

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ]
];
```